# How to develop sharepoint applications using office ui fabric?

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to use Office UI Fabric controls in my custom application which is on SharePoint Online.

I would like to use the panels used in Office 365 admin center.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the delay. Fabric team member here. What specifically would you like help with in terms of using Office UI Fabric? And, what kind of applications are you developing? Web parts, Graph-connected apps, or something else?

To start, you can check out full documentation on [Fabric's website](http://dev.office.com/fabric). There are samples for how to use each of Fabric's components in a React.js app, including the [Panel](http://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/panel). Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Hi Peter, 
sorry for the delay.

i would like to use fabric in my application , which is developing using jquery,REST. i would like to provide look and feel same like office 365 admin panel. please help me.

i already trying with your above mentioned sites